# Replace value stored in xml data in a stored procedure with id

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xpath

I have XML in the form:

```
<Books>
    <Book>
        <Name>Lord of the Rings</Name>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Name>Harry Potter</Name>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Name>Girl with the Dragon Tattoo</Name>
    </Book> 
</Books>
```

I then have a table containing two columns (Id and Name):

- 1: Lord of the Rings
- 2: Harry Potter
- 3: Girl with the Dragon Tattoo

Using TSQL, I want to update the XML to become:

```
<Books>
    <Book>
        <Name>1</Name>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Name>2</Name>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Name>3</Name>
    </Book> 
</Books>
```

As in, I need to do a lookup to the 'lookup' table and update the value of the nodes to be the ID instead of the name.

The only way I can think of doing this is to create a loop and to use XPath to extract the name, query the lookup table and then call modify on the XML using 'replace value of'. Is there a better way as I imagine my proposed solution will be very slow? The solution needs to be in TSQL and cannot be performed in business logic prior to calling the SP. I imagine there is a way to do this in a set based operation, but I am struggling to find it.

Comment: The sequence is 1 2 1, i think it should be  1 2 3.

Comment: Is that really your element names? Those are not valid XML element names so you can't use the XML data type to modify the content.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - I have updated the example as I picked a very poor example. No these were not the node names.

Comment: @Romil - In the first example the order of 1,2,1 was correct based on the lookup as there were two nodes with the same value. In the new updated example I have changed this as I think I was making it look more confusing that it needed to be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is an elegant solution, but to ensure there is an answer to help anybody else viewing this question, this was my solution:

```
DECLARE @BookId NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @BookName NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Counter INT
DECLARE @MaxCounter INT
SET @Counter = 1

SET @MaxCounter = @BooksXml.value('count(/Books/Book)', 'int')

WHILE @Counter <= @MaxCounter
BEGIN
    SET @BookName = @BooksXml.value('(/Books/Book[sql:variable("@Counter")]/Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
    SELECT @BookId=CAST(ProductID AS NVARCHAR(10)) FROM Book WHERE Name = @BookName

    SET @BooksXml.modify('replace value of (/Books/Book[sql:variable("@Counter")]/Name/text())[1] with sql:variable("@BookId")')

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're headed down the right path.  And I personally don't think it will be slow.  Or have you found otherwise?

Consider this example from MSDN @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190675.aspx

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml
SET @myDoc = '<Root>
<Location LocationID="10" 
            LaborHours=".1"
            MachineHours=".2" >Manu steps are described here.
<step>Manufacturing step 1 at this work center</step>
<step>Manufacturing step 2 at this work center</step>
</Location>
</Root>'
--SELECT @myDoc
```

I would think this right here is a very quick operation:

```
SET @myDoc.modify('
  replace value of (/Root/Location[1]/@LaborHours)[1]
  with (
       if (count(/Root/Location[1]/step) > 3) then
         "3.0"
       else
          "1.0"
      )
')
SELECT @myDoc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I appreciate you taking the time to reply.

I agree that the example you have posted should be fast. However, if there were multiple Location nodes, how would you update all of the LaborHours attributes? My proposal was to effective loop over the code you have above calling it once for each target node in the XML. Whilst the data set isn't overly large, I thought there might be a faster way. 

+1 as I think your answer is constructive to this problem.